# Android: adb: copy file to /system (Permission denied)

Tags: android, permissions, push, adb

actually I try to install busybox on my HTC Desire. Therefore I try to copy a busybox-binary to /system/bin. So I remounted /system with rw:

```
mount -o rw,remount -t ext3 /dev/block/mmcblk1p21 /system
```

After this I didn't get a "Read-only file system"-error. But now I'm experiencing "Permission denied" when trying to push the file to /system/bin.
I also tried pushing my file to /sdcard and then move this to /system/bin, but this doesn't work either:

```
$ mv /sdcard/busybox /system/bin
failed on '/sdcard/busybox' - Cross-device link
```

Some ideas, how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not a programming question and does not belong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `mount` to check if the device really was remounted as RW.

The same error happened to me, then I simply made a cp orig dest and then a rm on orig, weird but seams mv behaves this way.

Comment: FYI, by default android does not have 'cp'

Answer (score 31):

Mounting is not enough, you have to run as root (this is the reason for permission denied).
This is how I push busybox:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb push busybox /system/bin
```

I run into some devices that you need to remount with `mount -o remount,rw /system` and not with `adb remount`.

Comment: For me , it shows `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`

Comment: How do I check that busyBox exists and can be used? is it enough to check if the file "/system/bin/busybox" exists?

Comment: @androiddeveloper It is not enough to check /system/bin, while it is a good place for busybox to reside, busybox could be anywhere. Use find to scan your Android, or just push a new busybox bin into your phone.

Comment: @OfirLuzon it can be even outside of "/system" ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, I dont have my dev/test env to test it, but since it is Linux, I bet you can put it anywhere you like.

Comment: @OfirLuzon ok, can you please tell me what is the best command to find it? also, I think that even if the search was successful, it might not work, since it's just a file name. anybody could create a file with this name... I'm not sure what's the best way to check if busybox is available.

Comment: @androiddeveloper, `find / -name busybox` will search for a busybox file everywhere (it will be a long operation). If you want to see that it is indeed a busybox bin file and not a dummy that someone decided to rename to busybox, just try to run it and see what you get(any command will do, e.g. `./busybox ls`).

Comment: @OfirLuzon Isn't it easier then to just run it instead of searching for it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper You can try, but it is possible that it is not in the $PATH, or it might not be even installed (you can still use it, e.g `./busybox ls`).

Comment: @OfirLuzon buy why would a user put it without really setting a the $PATH for it, as that's the main method of using its functions...?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Your line of questions led me to believe that you want to find "hidden" busybox, as clearly you can try to run one busybox command to see if it installed and in the $PATH

Comment: @OfirLuzon I just want to know it's ready to be used. so if you say this command is enough, ok.

Comment: mount: permission denied (are you root?) . Yes, It's rooted.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure but since you asked for ideas I'll mention that I never specified the -t option.

`mount -o remount,rw /system`

always worked for me

Answer (score 2):

mv just moves a hardlink *within a single filesystem*. If you want to move files between two filesystems you need to copy and then delete the original.
e.g.

```
if ( cp -R /sdcard/busybox /system/bin ); then
rm -fR /sdcard/busybox
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If some command is not working, try putting busybox in front of it. (if installed)

f.ex.

```
root@android:/ # mv /sdcard/androidLTheme/bootanim/bootanimation.zip /system/media/
failed on '/sdcard/androidLTheme/bootanim/bootanimation.zip' - Cross-device link
root@android:/ # _
```

but

```
root@android:/ # busybox mv /sdcard/androidLTheme/bootanim/bootanimation.zip /system/media/
root@android:/ # _
```