# Corrupt TAR archive after replacing a single file: Skipping to next header

Tags: file, tar

I've made a backup with TWRP of the Android system partition. It consists of a startup video that I want to replace by my own.

The main idea is to remove the start.mp4 from the archive, extract the folder, copy the new start.mp4 in that folder and than update the archive's directory. But after that, the archive seems to be corrupt.

Here is a more detailed description what I've done:

**List the content of the original file**

```
$ tar -tvf system.ext4.tar
> ...
> -rw-r--r-- root/root      1822 2014-08-22 11:22 /system/media/silence.wav
> -rw-r--r-- root/root    970069 2016-11-29 12:19 /system/media/start.mp4
> drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-29 13:58 /system/preload/
> ...
```

You can see the original start.mp4 which has a size of ~950 KByte.

**Delete the old start.mp4 in the archive**

```
$ tar --delete --file=system.ext4.tar /system/media/start.mp4
```

**Make sure that the file is deleted**

```
$ tar -tvf system.ext4.tar
> ...
> -rw-r--r-- root/root    619252 2008-08-01 14:00 /system/media/poweroff_land.mp4
> -rw-r--r-- root/root      1822 2014-08-22 11:22 /system/media/silence.wav
> drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-29 13:58 /system/preload/
> ...
```

**Extract /system/media directory**

```
$ tar -xvf system.ext4.tar /system/media
> tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
> /system/media/
> /system/media/audio/
> ...
```

**Copy the new start.mp4 into /system/media**

```
$ cp start.mp4 system/media/
```

**Update the /system/media directory**

```
$ tar --update --verbose --file=system.ext4.tar system/media
> tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
> system/media/start.mp4
```

**List the files of the updated archive**

```
$ tar -tvf system.ext4.tar
> ...
> -rw-r--r-- root/root      1822 2014-08-22 11:22 /system/media/silence.wav
> -rw-r--r-- root/root    970069 2016-11-29 12:19 /system/media/start.mp4
> drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-29 13:58 /system/preload/
> ...
> tar: Skipping to next header
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

As you can see, there is a start.mp4 but with the same size as in the original archive (the new one has a size of ~50 KByte) and obviously that an error has occurred.

Have you any idea how to replace the start.mp4?

Comment: What version of `tar`?

Comment: tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1

Comment: If some one else want to change files of the system partition, I've found a way of doing this while Android is running (root access required): 1) `adb shell`, 2) login as root `su` 3) remount the system partition writable `mount -o remount,rw /system` 4) copy your file e. g. `cp /sdcard start.mp4 /system/media`. It is based on this SO anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864907/android-adb-copy-file-to-system-permission-denied#answer-13339661

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by specifying a blocksize (e.g. -b 64) as described at https://web.archive.org/web/20171016165801/http://www.digitesters.com/add-file-to-existing-tar-archive/

In my case, I was creating a tar file in Mac OSX and then adding new files to the tar on Centos Linux.  The first file added fine, but the second gave the `Skipping to next header` error.  adding `-b 64` on the tar creation in OSX seemed to fix it.