# Is it possible to push ADB System files without Root?

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

I'm looking to replace the `Generic.kl` file on my Samsung. I found a command online to push this file:

```
adb push Generic.kl /system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl
```

But when I tried it says:

> "Couldn't create file: Read-only file system"

I assume this is because I'm not a root user. Can I do it some other way? *(Fast-boot mode is not supported on Samsung)*

Thanks!

Comment: This is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android you need to remount your file system

Comment: @user4463546 that needs root, so the answer is "no" either way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10864907/1778421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need root.

That error isn't a permission denial, though. On Android, the system partition is mounted read-only by default. To make changes, you need to use

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

That command requires root privileges as well, so it won't run.

Even if system were mounted in read-write mode, you'd just get

> Couldn't create file: Permission denied

system is owned by the user `root`. Permissions inside of system are, at their most lenient, set to `755` or `rwxr-xr-x`. That means only the `root` user has permission to write anywhere in system. Since ADB runs under the `shell` user, you can't write files.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Is there any way then to remap a hardware button without root (without an .apk either)?

Comment: I don't think so.